# How to create an NSFetchRequest which filters Core Data objects based on attributes AND relationships?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a Core Data model setup like so:

- **Blockbuster** Entity

  - To-Many relationship to **DVD** entities.
- **DVD** Entity

  - **title** attribute (string)
  - To-One relationship to a parent **Blockbuster** entity

A single Blockbuster can have multiple DVD's inside of it (To-Many).  Each DVD can only be part of a single Blockbuster (To-One).

There are multiple Blockbuster's, and some may contain DVD entities which share the same title as DVD entities from other Blockbuster's.  For example, *Blockbuster A* might have a copy of "Transformers 2", and so does *Blockbuster C* and *Blockbuster G*.  Let's pretend no Blockbuster has more than one copy of the same titled movie.

I'm interested in grabbing the *Transformers 2* DVD from *Blockbuster C*.  I don't want the copies from *Blockbuster A* or *G*, because my boss frequents there, and I can only get away with burning this piece of garbage in *Blockbuster C*.

---

My question is, how do I form an NSFetchRequest which grabs a **DVD** with the **title** "Transformers 2", which is a child of the **Blockbuster** "C" parent entity?

This type of request will grab all the "Transformer 2" DVD's, but not the one specific to the Blockbuster C entity:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];

NSString *aTitle = @"Transformers 2";
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@", aTitle];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"DVD" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

// error handling code
[request release];
```

Is there a way to pass, say, the Object ID of a related object inside the NSPredicate, filtering based on that?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can traverse relationships in an `NSPredicate`. For example, you could write something like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@ AND blockbuster.name LIKE \"Blockbuster C\"", @"Transformers 2"]
```

Now, if you don't have a property to compare against and you need to check actual objects, then you could use something like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title == %@ AND blockbuster IN %@", @"Transformers 2", setOfBlockbusters]
```

The full syntax is documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795). But `setOfBlockbusters` could be a set, an array, or a dictionary (if it's a dictionary, the values, not the keys, are used).

Comment: Thanks so much, that did it!  And thanks for the link to the docs.  Very helpful.  :)