# Retrieve Specific Object from Core Data

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

I'm new to `Core Data` and wondering if it is possible to get an object based on it's attributes, more specifically, an uniqueID I assigned to it. I'm trying to do this because I'm interfacing with a web server, which provides data that will updated the `Core Data`. I want to search through each of the web server objects, check the timestamp, and if it's different, retrieve that object from core data, and update. I've looked at using `existingObjectWithId` but it seems like I would have to know which object I'm searching for, or the ID of that object. I've also thought about sorting the data in both arrays, and then checking each simultaneously, but didn't think that is viable.

Here is what I'm doing so far:

```
-(NSMutableArray*) updateRootBeers:(NSMutableArray*)webRootBeerList{
    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]initWithEntityName:@"Rootbeer"];
    coreDataRootBeerList = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]mutableCopy];
    //check to see if core data has data, if not, call function to populate the list
    if (coreDataRootBeerList.count <=0) {
        [self addRootBeerToCoreData:webRootBeerList];
    }else{
        //otherwise I want to update the core data object if object data is different.
        for(RootBeer* currentRootBeer in webRootBeerList){
            RootBeer* mRootBeer = [moc existingObjectWithId:currentRootBeer error:nil];
        }
    }



}
```

I've also thought about using nested for loops to check for the data in each array, but that seems like poor coding.
Any help or thoughts would be great.

Comment: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527966/how-to-create-an-nsfetchrequest-which-filters-core-data-objects-based-on-attribu) might get you started on the right track

Comment: I think that might work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make an [NSFetchRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html). You can set the entity and provide a Predicate. Really simple and clean.